# R Leaflet Map Showing in Console but not Markdown

Tags: r, leaflet, markdown

This map has worked for me in the past, but now when I'm running it in iosslides I'm getting the following result (see image). I think I've updated all my packages, and the map loads fine in the console. I've grabbed the code for this slide alone - it should all be contained here. Any ideas what's going on?[result in r markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK1u1.jpg)

````
```{r fig.width=8, fig.height=4, fig_align="center", echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, tidyr, readr, tigris, acs, magrittr, foreign, ggplot2, gridExtra, ggthemes, leaflet, maps )

#map

la_trad_school_perf_map_layers <- leaflet(lac_schools) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  setView(-118.4, 34.05, zoom = 9) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    radius = 3,
    color = ~pal_measure(Math_Prof_Category_1516),
    stroke= FALSE, 
    fillOpacity = 1,
    popup=school_popup,
    group="15-16 Math Proficiency Rates"
  ) %>%
  addPolygons(data = income_200k_plus_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_income(plus_200k_pct), 
              color = "Greens",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              popup = popup_200k, 
              group="% of Households with Income > $200k - 2015")%>%
  addPolygons(data = poverty_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_poverty(poverty_rate), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              #popup = popup_poverty, 
              group="% of Residents in Poverty - 2015")%>%
  addPolygons(data = unemployment_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_unemp(unemp_rate_2064), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              #popup = popup_poverty, 
              group="% of Unemployed Adults - 2015")%>%
  addPolygons(data = commute_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_commute(commute_perc_60_more), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              #popup = popup_poverty, 
              group="% of Adults with a Commute > 60 min.")%>%
  addPolygons(data = ed_attain_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_ed_attain(lt_hs_degree_rate_18_44), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              #popup = popup_ed_attain, 
              group="% of Adults Without a HS Degree - 2015")%>%
  addPolygons(data = cit_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_cit(non_citizenship_rate), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              popup = popup_cit, 
              group="Non-U.S. Citizen - 2015")%>%
  addPolygons(data = grandchildren_merged, 
              fillColor = ~pal_grandchildren(living_with_grand_rate), 
              color = "#b2aeae",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, 
              weight = 1, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              popup = popup_grandchildren, 
              group="% of Children Raised by Grandparents - 2015")%>%
  #addMarkers(data=la_homicides_assaults,
    #         la_homicides_assaults$lat, 
     #        la_homicides_assaults$lng,
      #       group="Incidents of Violent Crime - 2015") %>%
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups=c("% of Households with Income > $200k - 2015", 
                 "% of Residents in Poverty - 2015", 
                 "% of Unemployed Adults - 2015", 
                 "% of Adults with a Commute > 60 min.", 
                 "% of Adults Without a HS Degree - 2015",
                 "% of Non U.S. Citizens - 2015", 
                 "% of Children Raised by Grandparents - 2015"),
    overlayGroups=c("15-16 Math Proficiency Rates"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
la_trad_school_perf_map_layers
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try add "redult='as-is'" in first line (that with {}).
Or - if you render to html - save prepared leaflet widget (using htmltools::savewidget) as separate .html file and then include it into final html using iframe.